# Change a user's password in ejabberd over xmpp

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

Is it possible for the admin to change a user's password through XMPP in ejabberd? After I logged in the admin account, I issued the following stanza:

```
<iq type="set" id="change6075" from="admin@example.com">
 <query xmlns="jabber:iq:register">
  <username>user1</username>
  <password>code1</password>
 </query>
</iq>
```

But it doesn't work, how can I modify a user's password over XMPP using the admin account?

Answer (score 3):

You can change the user password with the help of mod_admin_extra command:

$ ejabberdctl change-password User Host newPassword

Comment: Is that possible to do via xml or via php script instead of executing commands

Comment: I believe this command spells "change_password" (underscore instead of hyphen) in modern ejabberd.

Comment: @Błotosmętek you're right. That is the correct spelling

Comment: @Błotosmętek, never mind. My bad. Both the hyphen and the underscore versions of the command work.